# Is there a service available to help continuously check for plagiarism online?

Tags: copyright

We have a website with several thousand pages and it is frequently copied elsewhere; we'd like to know when and where this takes place to so we can make sure we are attributed correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plagiarism Today has a [resource page](http://www.plagiarismtoday.com/stopping-internet-plagiarism/1-how-to-find-plagiarism/) with a bunch of tools for use in various contexts(feeds, images, etc.) The standard for text content for some time now seems to be [Copyscape](http://www.copyscape.com/), and their [Copysentry](http://www.copyscape.com/signup.php?pro=0&o=f) is a paid and automated service.

You should give that page a scan for some other techniques you'd probably want to consider.

Answer (score 2):

[FairShare](https://fairshare.attributor.com/fairshare/) offers a free service that tries to automatically detect where and when your content is being reused, based on an RSS feed you supply.

Supply your feed address in the first step, then choose "I don't license my content" in the second step (unless you want to license it for reuse):

[image: FairShare check for website plagiarism]

Click the link they send you by email, and FairShare then publishes two RSS feeds that you can subscribe to containing sites reusing your content (one containing all examples of reuse separately and one with a weekly summary). They say that there can be a delay of 12 hours between a site reusing your content and them detecting it.

You could also include unique codes/keywords in your content and set up [Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts) to detect them.

Comment: I tested fairshare but sadly it wasn't sensitive enough compared with copyscape. Copyscape came up with a number of sites that ripped us off, sadly fairshare came up with none.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts) to notify you whenever Google finds a page that contain you specify. In your case you would have Google look for unique text in your pages.